# select particular items ordered n times

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables, one invoice and the other the details where i need to select products ordered n times by a particular customer within a date range

the tables in part looks like this

**Invoice**

```
invid | custid | invdate
----------------------------
101   | 11     | 2014-2-10
102   | 22     | 2014-2-15
103   | 22     | 2014-3-01
104   | 11     | 2014-3-14
```

**Details**

```
invid | item     
------------
101   | bread   
102   | bread  
103   | chips
104   | chips
102   | bread   
103   | bread  
104   | chips
101   | bread
```

from the code above, i need to select say all customers who ordered the same items 2 times or more within `2014-2-10`  and `2014-3-09`, *excluding any customer who purchased the same item in the week `2014-3-10` to `2014-3-14`*

for example

**if customer orders `bread` 2 times between date1 and date2 and did not order the same `bread` between date3 and date4 then it should be in the output**

and date the expected output should be

```
custid  | item  | item_count
22      | bread | 2
```

the custid 11 would have NOT fit the list, because they also purchased in the week `2014-3-10` to `2014-3-14`, but it they did not purchased the same item in the passed dates

this is what i tried

```
SELECT 
i.custid, d.ITEM,COUNT(d.ITEM) as orders
From `details` d 
LEFT JOIN `invoices` i on i.invid= d.invid 
WHERE 
i.invdate >= '2014-2-10' AND 
i.invdate <= '2014-3-14' AND 
i.custid NOT IN 
(SELECT custid FROM `invoices` WHERE invdate >= '2014-3-10') 
Group By i.invid, d.ITEM 
HAVING COUNT(d.ITEM) >= 2
```

when i run again the full table, i get 1 item instead of 6. I did manually using excel through a number of functions to be sure, in this case none

Comment: you are not specifying enough information. for example what is `invnum`?

Comment: i updated, it was `invid`

Comment: you also select i.custid twice

Comment: why would the output contain customer 22? He ordered two items but they are not same , right ?

Comment: It's getting blurry somehow. Why is 11/nuts in the output? Both rules are violated! The nuts were *not* purchased in the first week and they *were* purchased in the *second week*.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are correct, i removed it, can you help , thanks?

Comment: @Smith: Help with what? I gave you an answer already. Is that not working? If so: What is not working? What record do you get although you shouldn't get it? Or what record don't you get although you should get it? I see no flaw in my answer.

Comment: thanks, i got an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical MySQL error. You mistakenly group by invid instead of custid.

```
SELECT 
i.custid, d.ITEM, COUNT(d.ITEM) as orders
From `details` d 
LEFT JOIN `invoices` i on i.invid= d.invid 
WHERE 
i.invdate >= '2014-2-10' AND 
i.invdate <= '2014-3-14' AND 
i.custid NOT IN 
(SELECT custid FROM `invoices` WHERE invdate >= '2014-3-10') 
Group By i.custid, d.ITEM 
HAVING COUNT(d.ITEM) >= 2;
```

EDIT: Okay, here is a closer look at it.

- Correct the GROUP BY as already mentioned.
- You outer join invoices although there should be no details record without an invoices record. Change this to INNER JOIN.
- You are confusing dates. The purchase date shall be between '2014-2-10' and '2014-3-09' and must not be between '2014-3-10' to '2014-3-14'
- Then: You don't want to exclude customers who bought something in that latter week. You want to exclude customer-item combinations that occured then.

My suggestion: select from both date ranges and check then if all macthes for a customer-item combination are within the desired week and still have a count of at least two:

```
select 
  i.custid, 
  d.item,
  count(d.item) as orders
from invoices i
inner join details d on d.invid = i.invid
where i.invdate between '2014-2-10' and '2014-3-09' 
   or i.invdate between '2014-3-10' and '2014-3-14'
group by i.custid, d.item 
having count(*) >= 2 and max(i.invdate) between '2014-2-10' and '2014-3-09;
```

Comment: hello, there is a clarification, i clarified the question

Comment: As far as I see it, this query matches your request perfectly. Only your example in your request doesn't match the description. So maybe you wanted to ask something else?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT    i1.custid, d1.ITEM, COUNT(*) orders
FROM      (invoices i1 JOIN details d1 USING (invid))
LEFT JOIN (invoices i2 JOIN details d2 USING (invid))
       ON i2.custid = i1.custid
      AND d2.ITEM   = d1.ITEM
      AND i2.invdate BETWEEN '2014-03-10' AND '2014-03-14'
WHERE     i1.invdate BETWEEN '2014-02-10' AND '2014-03-09'
      AND i2.custid IS NULL
GROUP BY  i1.custid, d1.ITEM
HAVING    orders >= 2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c71e8/4/0).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it did not take into account the item. it is suppose to be items that a given customer 
ordered n times or more times between date1 and date2, but that did not order at all in the current week.

Comment: @Smith: In that case, you're after an anti-join; one way to implement that in MySQL is using an outer join and then filtering for results for which the outer join did not match - see my updated answer.  However, on this basis you surely would want both customers 11 and 22 in the resultset of your example data since only chips were purchased during the exclusion period (invoice 104)?